# Can't connect my school laptop to my homegroup

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

Well I've been trying quite a lot of things, it worked to connect through my other laptop which is not given by my school so there's nothing wrong with the homegroup itself. But I need a way to connect this "domain owned laptop" into my homegroup. It has IPv6 working, all the services are started and I've also deleted idstore.sst without success.

EDIT: The error that comes up is "Windows cannot set up homegroup on this computer"

Checking through this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617166(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Do the policies set on the system *allow* it to be on a homegroup?

Comment: Have you read through this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-can-t-I-join-a-homegroup

Comment: I have read through http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-can-t-I-join-a-homegroup.

How can I check that Shinrai?

Comment: A good friend of mine told me to run gpedit.msc, unfortunately I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Can you change your network location to home, or does that require admin creds? Microsoft lists a couple of GPOs affecting Homegroups here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617166%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: The network location is already set to home, so that's not the case, but thanks for input.

Comment: No further progress.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Network Discovery in Windows 7.  Goto Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Services and see if 'Peer Networking Grouping' service is enabled and running.